Envoy proxy react frontend grpc connection error to go server
I have a go server serving a proto using grpc and I want to call it from react frontend.
Server:
lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9090")
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Failed to listen on port 9090: %v", err)
}

s := asset.Server{}
grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
asset.RegisterAssetServiceServer(grpcServer, &s)

if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Failed to server gRPC server over port 9090: %v", err)
}

I am creating a client and calling grpc
 let service = new AssetServiceClient("http://localhost:8080" );
 let request = new Message()
 request.setBody("body")
 const response = service.getAssets(request);
 console.log(response);

I have envoy configuration listening on port 8080 and redirecting to port 9090
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          access_log:
            - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: echo_service
                  timeout: 0s
                  max_stream_duration:
                    grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                  - prefix: "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                max_age: "1728000"
                expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
          - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
  - name: echo_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    typed_extension_protocol_options:
      envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
        explicit_http_config:
          http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: cluster_0
      endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
          - endpoint:
              address:
                socket_address:
                  address: host.docker.internal
                  port_value: 9090

and I am running it in docker
services:
  envoy:
    image: envoyproxy/envoy:dev-e48666365c8a0b3a62343602fd9380d58a7afd95
    ports:
      - "9901:9901"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml

However I am having problems, I get 503 error when trying to call my grpc. I have enabled logs in envoy and this is what I am getting: https://pastebin.com/WiN31p5B
I see here 2 logs messages mentioning the issue:

'grpc-message', 'upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: Connection refused'
However I don't see any further logs on how to debug this or where the problem is located.
connection in progress ... not creating a new connection, shouldCreateNewConnection returned false. There is a problem with creating a connection to my server but no further message why.

I have created a temporary go client to call my go server and connection is working correctly, so the issue should not be with my server not accepting connection, that's why I am looking for problems in envoy.
conn, err := grpc.NewClient(":9090", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("could not connect: %s", err)
}
defer conn.Close()

c := asset.NewAssetServiceClient(conn)
message := asset.Message{
  Body: "body",
}

response, err := c.GetAssets(context.Background(), &message)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Error when calling GetAssets: %s", err)
}

